# How to use reactjs material ui GRID layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to use `@mui/material/Grid` layout for a use case,
In my Report component, I want to have the Bar and Line charts in one block
and the Doughnut and PolarArea charts in another,

I tried applying CSS by adding, `style = {{display: "inline-block"}}`,
But the UX looks like this -
[image]

By code is like this on a high level -
App.js -

```
function App() {
return (
    <Router>
      <Container style={{backgroundColor: '#F3F4F6'}}>
        <Grid container spacing={0.5} >
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<SignIn />}/>
              <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard/>}/>
            </Routes>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Dashboard.js component -

```
const Dashboard = () => {
    return (<>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Table/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Report/>
        </Grid>
    </>
)}
```

Report.js component -

```
export function Report() {
    return <>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Bar options={barChartOptions} data={barChartData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Line options={areaChartOptions} data={areaChartData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <Doughnut options={doughnutOptions} data={doughnutChatData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={6}>
      <PolarArea options={polarAreaOptions} data={polarAreaData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Bar options={groupedBarOptions} data={groupedBarData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
    </Grid>
  </>
}
```

Comment: Is it because each contained item is just slightly larger than half the width of the container (even by just one pixel is enough), and so each one winds up on the next line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should wrap up the Grid items with a Grid container.

```
export function Report() {
    return <>
    <Grid container>
       <Grid item xs={6}>
         <Bar options={barChartOptions} data={barChartData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
         <Line options={areaChartOptions} data={areaChartData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
        <Doughnut options={doughnutOptions} data={doughnutChatData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={6}>
         <PolarArea options={polarAreaOptions} data={polarAreaData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <Grid item xs={12}>
      <Bar options={groupedBarOptions} data={groupedBarData} style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}/>
    </Grid>
  </>
}
```

Comment: should I remove GRID from App.js and Dashboard.js? and only use the GRID wrappers in the components where needed? what is the best practice?

Comment: Yes you can remove the GRID wrappers from App.js, and use them only in Components.